# Bind string on placeholder to PDF with c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pdf, data-binding

I have a document in PDF. And on some text/placeholder for example '{text}' I want to bind data/overwrite the '{text}' with my string from c#. How is this possible?

My data is just simple string.

I am looking for something like this:

```
PdfTest file = new PdfTest('file.pdf');
file.replace("{text}", text);
file.save()
```

Any working example?

Comment: Make it clear what is text ? are you using binding ? are you in WPF application ?

Comment: text is just string. wpf/winform/console It doesn't matter

Comment: so you want to replace the text with some other string ?

Comment: yes, just this thing

Comment: Editing PDFs is difficult in general (there are some documents allowing easy editing to some degree but a generic solution is difficult or even impossible). I would propose using form fields which indeed are easy to fill using general purpose PDF libraries.